# Where to include type definition file in new angular webpack setup

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webstorm, angular-cli

We recently moved to latest angular 2.0 and have started using angular-cli, webpack to build our application. As of now when we use ng test, build etc, application runs fine and gives desired output, however, the automatic compilation (using webstorm) always throw lots of error. Earlier we used to provide a main.ts which in term refers to other d.ts files. main.ts was used in tsconfig.json. So everything was smooth without any error.
e.g. a simple test like this will throw static compilation error for describe, it, expect.

```
describe("it is a suite",()=>{
it("it is a test",()=>{
expect(1).toBe(2);
})
});
```

if I include jasmine.d.ts file reference in this test file, everything goes away.

including import from '@angular/core/testing' throws error that there are no such exported member.

So, the question - Where and how should we include the type definition file to avoid this static compilation?

more information - In webstorm settings, I have selected bundled (1.8.10) version and with enabled typescript compiler I am using tsconfig.json

tsconfig.json has content from angular-cli project [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/f6fa1a5218e9b43ab3ce29151a95efe915742562/packages/angular-cli/blueprints/ng2/files/__path__/tsconfig.json)
with addition in files section to include main.ts and typings.d.ts

typing.d.ts has nothing where as main.ts includes reference to other d.ts file referenced under the 'typings' folder under root.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your TypeScript configuration in WebStorm.

Angular requires TypeScript version 2 or higher. One of the main reasons for this is to reconcile type information via npm packages installed under the `@types` scope.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/f6fa1a5218e9b43ab3ce29151a95efe915742562/packages/angular-cli/blueprints/ng2/files/package.json#L36) `@types/jasmine` is a dev dependency which will supply the type information for `describe`, `it` and `expect`.

Comment: I'm not using webstorm, but from when I did their docs were pretty good... I'd suggest starting there... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/typescript.html

Answer (score 0):

Webstorm Typescript Configuration for Angular 2

If you work with the actual angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.17 you need to **change your typescript version** from bundled version 1.8.10 **to** the the typescript version **2.0.2** 
which is installed by angular-cli via package.json.

This can be done:

in the dialog

settings/languages & frameworks/typescript/Configure TypeScript Compiler

**Choose custom directory** to:  "YourProjectDir"/\node_modules\typescript\lib

in the dialog
settings/languages & frameworks/typescript

**check** Compiler Enable Type Script Compiler and
**select** use tsconfig.json

as you have allready done.

This is all you have to do.
You **don't need** to install any typings for jasmine (any longer). This is done by angular-cli with @types/jasmine as @Brocco has described in his answer.

If you don't use Angular-cli:

```
npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev
```